# Integration of Zend_Auth and Zend_Acl with Zend_Amf_Server

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-acl, zend-amf

Has anyone succesfully integrated Zend_Auth and Zend_Acl with Zend_Amf_Server? I'am looking for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

See below a link which helped me.
http://www.flexphperia.net/en/programming/php/client-authentication-and-authorization-in-zend-amf-server